# Toggle dropdown and hide on outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got this dropdown menu which works, but I would also like it to close when I click outside it… I've tried some answered solutions but something's wrong and I can't figure it out..Could someone point what am I missing out here? Thanks a lot

```js
$("#toggle").on('click', function() {
   $(".dropdown").toggleClass("dropdown--visible");
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hide();
});

$(".dropdown").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown--visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">Toggle dropdown</button>

<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This vanilla-flavored solution uses a `handleDropdown` function that checks two conditions:
 - Was the toggle button clicked?
 - Is the dropdown currently hidden?

If both are true, it shows the dropdown. Otherwise, it hides the dropdown.

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0],
      toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
document.addEventListener("click", handleDropdown);

function handleDropdown(event){
  if(event.target == toggle && dropdown.style.display != "block"){
    dropdown.style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
    dropdown.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Toggle dropdown</button>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#toggle").on('blur click', function() {
   $(".dropdown").toggleClass("dropdown--visible");
});

$(document).click(function(){
    
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown--visible {
  display: block!important;
}
.dropdown--invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">Toggle dropdown</button>

<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but this won't close it on the button click

Comment: Changed and fixed close it when button click

Answer (score 2):

You have setup a click event listener for document and it will execute all the time when you click anywhere.
You can use a common class to filter out the dropdown events.

```
<button id="toggle" class="dd">Toggle dropdown</button>

<div class="dropdown dd">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('dd')) {        
    $(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown--visible");
  }
});
```

Also better use **removeClass()** without using **hide()** since hide() adds a display:none; directly to the element and will be hard to control.